# Document Viewer for .doc, docx, .xlx, .xlsx and .ppt files

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery

I need a document viewer for **.doc, .docx, .ppt, .xlx, and .xlsx** file formats, that allow me to view above files in browser. I took 4-5 days googling to find a free or less costly solution providing me the solution but all in vain. I have visited almost all the recommendations on stack overflow and other sites like that, but unable to find a feasible solution.

So what i need is to view the above files in browser. 
**Recommended Languages:**

Java
Javascript
Jquery
HTML5
CSS3

**Servers & Frameworks:** 
1. IBM Webshpere Application Server

Note: Provided that there is no internet access to the systems upon which the application will be hosted neither on the client machines!

I'll highly appreciate for your time to help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you integrate with Alfresco, or at least reuse the source code (GNU-LGPL) or concept of Alfresco.

Here is what Alfresco does, among other things:

- On the server side, generate a browser-viewable lightweight version of each office document (.doc, docx, .xlx, .xlsx, .ppt) on the server, as a background task.
- When a web request comes for a particular office document, serve this lightweight version of that document in a web page.

Here is how it looks like (central left panel):

[image]
*https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alfresco-community-201707-online-document-preview.png*

Free, open source.
Alfresco is all written in Java, but it calls (by command line) headless LibreOffice to convert documents.